# how to capture dynamic conversion values on Google ads?

Tags: woocommerce, google-tag-manager, google-ads-script

I am trying to get dynamic the order total price on my thankyou page(the page seeing the user after a successful order) to the google ads report through the goole-tag-manager chrome extension.

The google ads snippet I am using on my thankyou page is this:

*I have follow the google support before (https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6095947?hl=en)

```
<!-- Event snippet for Purchase conversion page -->
            <script>   
            gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                'send_to': 'My Conversion ID/My Conversion Label',
                'value': 11.50,
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'transaction_id': ''
            });

            </script>
```

and the order total amount is the " 'value': 11.50, "
So instead of 11.50 I am placing the below code

```
document.querySelector("#cost>.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").innerText.match(/^.{1}(.*).{0}/i)[1].trim();
```

so I can take the total for each order every time dynamicaly by scaning the dom, but doesn't work. Are my thoughts right? Is this the right way to do it by addin code manually on my site without use gootle tag manager?  Any Ideas about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its actually quite simple when you do it with php.

```php
// Hook the function in head.
add_action('wp_head', 'bks_head_social_tracking_code');

function bks_head_social_tracking_code() {
    // Check if its thank you page.
    if(is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' )) {
        // Get order object.
        $order = wc_get_order(get_query_var('order-received'));

        // Get total.
        $order_total = $order->get_total();

        // Prepare.
        $output = "
      <script>
          gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                'send_to': 'My Conversion ID/My Conversion Label',
                'value': ". $order_total .", // Use dynamically.
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'transaction_id': ''
            });

    </script>";
         // echo.
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

> You can make the currency dynamic too. You can use this to to get different kinds of data. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: Bhanu, thank you very much for your answer! How can I implement your code. I have to added on my thankyou.php Or on the order-received.php ?

Comment: @atr0x, add it in your function.php

Comment: ThanX again for your help. Ok I replaced the send_to with my info and placed it in my function.php (and I remove the the gtag <script></script> from thankyou.php) Now I have to add "add_action" on my thankyou.php right?

Comment: hey @atr0x, No the complete code stays inside `functions.php`. From `add_action` to the function. You should reach about how action works here(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/). What this action does is runs when it is preparing the header. When it will run, it will check if its the thank you page or not and add the data according to our conditions. To test complete a test order and read thank you page, once you are there check your head tag you should see the above output `<script>` in there. This proves that your code worked.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I made a test and yes the code seems to work because in my head tag in thankyou page I see this output ```gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                'send_to': 'AW-360482519/jOXMCLKvs6sCENeN8qsB',
                'value': <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span>8,20</span>,
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'transaction_id': ''
            });
```

Comment: But on google tag manager on chrome extention, the section "Google ads conversion tracking" it disappeared like it doesn't placed the gtag script on thankyou page at all.

Comment: this which I've circled it.  take a look here: https://ibb.co/g6Jf2K8

Comment: Hey @atr0x, your question was basically about how to get dynamic data ans set its good. Which seems to be answered. I would request you to post a new question using this tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics.

Comment: @atr0x, what i can think out of my head is you have to make sure that your dynamic code that you have added should be after your google tracking code.

Comment: @atr0x, Also your output seems to be worong. `value` should only have integer value. rather than an html. Are you sure this isn't your old code ?

Comment: You were right! I didn't clear 100% my old code. I did it now and I am getting the correct output, here it is: ``` gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                'send_to': 'AW-360482519/jOXMCLKvs6sCENeN8qsB',
                'value': 8.15,
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'transaction_id': '' }); ```

Comment: … You are my savior, man!  :D Finally, I try to add only this section from your code: ```<?php $order_total = $order->get_total(); $output = "<script>
                      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                            'send_to': 'AW-my_id/my_key_here',
                            'value': ". $order_total .",
                            'currency': 'EUR',
                            'transaction_id': '' }); </script>";
                    echo $output;
            ?>```  Inside the thankyou.php And It worked like a charm!

Comment: It seems something goes wrong with the "wp_head" on the hook in your code. As I've read in the Google's support, the GTM script has to be placed inside the complete-order-page (thankyou-page, in my occasion) and NOT in the header of the site as it happens according to the way you suggested. Thanx again for your help.  :D

Comment: Great. I would appreciate it you can mark this as the correct answer and maybe upvote it. @atr0x

Comment: Thank you for the instruction, I would like to ask about the transaction_id, This is not loaded dynamically in the example, how could I do that? I am trying the get_transaction_id(); ?> but the field still remains empty. Thank you!